# How to kill a pop up message in a tool using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am invoking a tool using subprocess.Popen in Python. Since, I am developing an automation framework, I just need to load a script file in the tool and once the tool executes the script, I need to collect the log.

The problem is when I invoke the tool, it first comes up with a POP up message (like: "Does this RAID/SATA controller comply with AHCI specification?") which I need to either click 'Yes' or 'No' and then the tool loads the script.

Is there any way to kill this pop up message through my Python code itself and continue loading the script? Hope I am not asking for too much.

Comment: There is no direct way for doing this. But check with the tool documentation, U may find some arguments to pass with the open cmd, to start it without prompt.

Comment: Yes vijay, I am in touch with the tool vendor waiting for a positive reply.